# Generic function for malloc to accept all data type

Tags: c

Given a function as(it can use `malloc()` internally)as  `void* function_ptr(void *ptr, int size);`

where `void *ptr` is a void pointer and `size` is the number and in return it should allocate the memory depending on the data type. For `int`, it should allocate `4*size(considering 32 bit)` and for `char` `1*size`.
for example,

for integer data type, `function_ptr((void *)some_int_ptr, 10 )`
it should allocate `10 *4(32 bit)` = `40 bytes` and
`function_ptr((void *)some_char_ptr, 10 )`, 10 bytes should be allocated

Question is how can we typecast `void *` to `int`/`char`/`double` pointer as function does not know as which datatype was typecast to `void*` ?

It was a interview question, i tried answering as sending 1 more parameter which mentions the data type and hence we can allocate and assign memory but was not accepted as

`void* function_ptr(void *ptr, int size, int data_type);`

Comment: `#define allocate(pret, len) malloc((len) * sizeof *(pret))`? If you get it cast to `void*` the only (and unportable and sometimes wrong way) is to assume `sizeof(*ptr) == _Alignof(*ptr)`.

Comment: What was your interview question, word for word?

Comment: @n.m. : Write a function which takes void pointer and size and allocates memory depending on the size and data type, for int and 10, it should allocate 40 bytes and for a char and 10, it should allocate 10 bytes

Comment: so your question is only for **int** and **char** data types ?

Comment: @ashish The question really doesn't make sense. It says "data type" without it being at all clear what that is supposed to be the type of. I would have responded to that question with "data type **of what**?"

Comment: data type as int/char/double. @DavidSchwartz : I did not understood as well when only void pointer was provided, but again cannot question the interviewer

Comment: The question as stated makes zero sense. Either you don't remember it correctly or the interviewer hasn't done the best job, to put it mildly.

Comment: Is the void pointer already pointing to some allocated memory space? Or has it just been declared and passed in straight away?

Comment: @n.m. : I do remember very clearly as i was not able to answer :)

Comment: @Martinn : I asked that as well , it was just declared hence i wanted to use 1 more variable to determine data type

Comment: Maybe a trick question? That seems like the only logical answer, once a pointer is passed to that function, it gets casted(if not manually casted) to void *. From inside the function there's no way to detect the data type to which it originally pointer.

Comment: Perhaps you were supposed to explain why the question doesn't make sense. Perhaps you've just misinterpreted it then, and now remembering your misinterpretation rather than the actual question. Perhaps the interviewer has no clue. These are the possibilities I can think of.

Comment: The question is, what access does the "function" have to the data type?  If it's a macro, and the data type (or a pointer to it) is passed as an argument, then the macro can use `sizeof` to get what it needs.  If it's not a macro, then it needs to have the data type size passed to it.  I don't think there's any way around it.  Since they didn't accept the function version with the extra argument, the only thing left seems to be the macro solution.

Comment: @ashish I know what data type means. However, to talk about a data type, there has to be some thing whose type we are talking about. The question does not make clear what that thing is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't know the data type from inside the function, as there is no type information available. There are two options:

1) Either make the function work on the size in *bytes*, then it doesn't need to know the type. Perhaps this was actually what the interviewer meant?

2) Rewrite the function so that it includes type information somewhere.

There are also bad alternatives such as using global variables or replacing the function with a wrapper macro, but neither is recommended.

Comment: I write such function but it doesnt work (I have a few years break from C, maybe it's silly error. Could you take a look?)
https://onlinegdb.com/-gkRS5lSP

Comment: @Marcin_cyna Please ask it as a proper question with the ask question button and post the relevant part of the code here on this site.